# Table does not scroll with mousewheel on rows, only on scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a table surrounded by a div having overflow-y : scroll on it.

I does have a scrollbar when the content has an overflow, but when I try to scroll with the scrollwheel it does not scroll, only when I have the mouse exactly on top of the scrollbar...

Why ?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle with some code so we can see how you built your code? It's difficult to know what's wrong without seeing your code :)

Comment: I tried a  fiddle by copy pasting the raw rendered html into it, and then it works... maybe some interfering javascripts... I try some more

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I had a left float on the content area but I forgot a div clear below it. Now it works.